# Which PHP parameter do I need to tweak in order to fix the PHP APCU CACHING site status warning?

Tags: caching

I get a memory warning in my Drupal site, but I still have sufficient free memory on the server.

Which parameter do I need to tweak in order to fix this warning?

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the [`apc.shm_size` PHP configuration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/apcu.configuration.php#ini.apcu.shm-size). Set it to `64M` or higher and see how that looks.